# Principal generators of prime ideals is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{m}]$ for m=-1, -2, -3

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, prime-factorization

I'm reading Marcus "Number fields" book and at a certain point (page 52) in the chapter about prime decomposition he writes

> We now consider in detail the way in which primes p $\in \mathbb{Z}$ split in quadratic fields.
>
> Let $R=A \cap \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{m}]$, m squarefree.
>
> Recall that R has integral basis $\{1,
> \sqrt{m}\}$ and
>   discriminant 4m when $m\equiv 2\; or\; 3\; (mod\; 4)$, and integral basis $\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt{m}}{2}\}$ and
>   discriminant m when $m\equiv 1\; (mod\; 4)$.
>
> Let p be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Theorem 21 shows that there are just three possibilities:
>   $$ pR=\begin{cases}
> P^2&\Leftarrow f(P|p)=1\\
> P&\Leftarrow f(P|p)=2\\
> P_1P_2 &\Leftarrow f(P_1|p)=f(P_2|p)=1.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> **Theorem 25** With notation as above, we have:
>
> If p | m, then
>   $$ pR=(p,\sqrt
> {m})^2.$$
>
> If m is odd, then
>   $$ 2R= \begin{cases} (2,1+\sqrt
> {m})^2&\text{if $m\equiv 3\pmod4$}\\
> \left(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{m}}{2}\right)\left(2,\frac{1-\sqrt{m}}{2}\right) & 
> \text{if $m\equiv 1\pmod8$}\\
> \text{prime if $m\equiv 5\pmod8$.}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> If p is odd, $p\not| m$ then
>   $$ pR=\begin{cases} (p,n+\sqrt{m})(p,n-\sqrt{m})\; \text{if $m\equiv n^2 \pmod p$}\\
> \text{prime if $m$ is not a square mod $p$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   where in all relevant cases the factors are distinct.
>
> **Proof.** I'll skip this.
>
> *The prime ideals involved in these factorizations do not look like principal ideals,
>   but we know in certain cases they must be principal: for example when m = −1, -2
>   or −3 (exercises 7 and 14, chapter 1). Can you describe principal generators for the
>   various prime ideals in these two cases?*

Now my problem is that I don't understand what it means in the last question, how do I find the principal ideals, and whose prime ideals is he referring to.

Any help in understanding both the question and how to solve it would be welcomed.

Comment: The relevant rings of integers are Euclidean domains with the complex norm as a Euclidean norm. So you can compute gcd's with it more or less like you would do in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Factorizations have been given for the ideals $pR$ and $2R$; so these factors are presumably prime ideals; however they have been described by two generating elements, and the goal is to show that they are actually principal ideals.

Comment: Both very helpful comments, thanks

Comment: If $p = N(a+b\sqrt{m})$ then $pR=(a+b\sqrt{m})(a-b\sqrt{m})$. The question is: For which $m$ can we write $p =a^2-mb^2$? Take for example $11$. Pick the square mod $11$ of the numbers $1,2,\dots,10$, you will find $ -2 (=9 \mod 11), -7 (=4 \mod 11), 3, 5$ (and of course $1$). Then, for $m =-2,-7,3,5$ you know that $11R=(a+b\sqrt{m})(a-b\sqrt{m})$.

Comment: @DavideMotta can I contact you in private? I need to ask you a few things out of this specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-1)**

- $p|m\Rightarrow p=\pm 1$ but then trivially $(\pm1,\sqrt{-1})=(1)=R$;
- $-1$ is odd and $-1\equiv 3\; (mod\; 4)$ so we must check the second case and in it the first case
      $$ (2,1+\sqrt{-1})$$ here we suffice to notice that 
      $$ (1+i)(1-i)=2$$
      and so
      $$ (2,1+\sqrt{-1})=(1+\sqrt{-1})$$.
- In this case any odd p works and both cases are possible since $4^2=16=17-1$ but for examples the squares mod 3 are 1 and 0 whislt $-1\equiv 2\; (mod\; 3)$ 
      .\ Now we are working in an Euclidean domain so we have that, for this we suffice to be in a UFD since this is enoguh for the gcd to exist, $(p,n\pm i)\subset (gcd(p,n\pm i))$ but in a Euclidean domain we have the Euclidean alogrithm and so there is a combination of any two elements whose result is the gcd of them implying
    $$(p,n\pm i)= (gcd(p,n\pm i)).$$
    The last case is trivial since $pR=(p).$

**-2)**

- $p|m\Rightarrow p=\pm 1\wedge \pm 2$ but then $(\pm1,\sqrt{-1})=(1)=R$$$(\pm 2,\sqrt{-2})=(\sqrt{-2}) $$ an d actually this is true in all cases where m is a $\mathbb{Z}$ prime;
- 2 is even so we can skip the second case;
- In this case any odd p works and both cases are possible since for example $1^2+2\equiv0\; (mod\; 3)$ but we also have that  squares mod 5 are 4,1 and 0 whilst $-2\equiv 3\; (mod\; 5)$ 
      .\  Now we are working in an Euclidean domain so we have that, for this we suffice to be in a UFD since this is enoguh for the gcd to exist, $(p,n\pm \sqrt{-2})\subset (gcd(p,n\pm \sqrt{-2}))$ but in a Euclidean domain we have the Euclidean alogrithm and so there is a combination of any two elements whose result is the gcd of them implying
    $$(p,n\pm \sqrt{-2})= (gcd(p,n\pm \sqrt{-2})).$$
    The last case is trivial since $pR=(p).$

**-3)**

- For what we said in the previous case p=$\pm 1\Rightarrow (1,\sqrt{-3})=R$ and $p\neq \pm 1\Rightarrow (p,\sqrt{-3})=(\sqrt{-3})$ ;
- -3 is odd and $-3\equiv 5\; (mod\; 8)$ so we must check the second case and in it the third case that is trivial since $2R=(2);$
- In this case any odd p but 3 works and both cases are possible since $2^2=4\equiv-3\; (mod\; 7)$ but for examples the squares mod 5 are 4,1 and 0 whilst $-3\equiv 2\; (mod\; 5)$ 
      .\ Now we are working in an Euclidean domain so we have that, for this we suffice to be in a UFD since this is enoguh for the gcd to exist, $(p,n\pm \sqrt{-3})\subset (gcd(p,n\pm \sqrt{-3}))$ but in a Euclidean domain we have the Euclidean alogrithm and so there is a combination of any two elements whose result is the gcd of them implying
    $$(p,n\pm \sqrt{-3})= (gcd(p,n\pm \sqrt{-3})).$$
    The last case is trivial since $pR=(p).$